# Pandas - Access a cell within a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the following link: 
https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/course-search/section/?t=casma124

I indexed the dataframe in order to focus on Fall 2020. You can see that there are numbers showing how many 'Open Seats' there are. If you inspect element those numbers you can see that they are in a smaller sell under the main one. My python code outputs the following:

```
Section  Open Seats        Instructor Type Location              Schedule  \
0       A1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LEC  SCI B23  TR 11:00 am-12:15 pm   
1       A1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  NaN     ROOM     M 8:00 pm-9:45 pm   
2       B1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LEC  SCI B23    TR 5:00 pm-6:15 pm   
3       B1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  NaN     ROOM     M 8:00 pm-9:45 pm   
4       D1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PSY B39   W 11:15 am-12:05 pm   
5       D2         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PSY B39    W 12:20 pm-1:10 pm   
6       D3         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PSY B39     W 1:25 pm-2:15 pm   
7       D4         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PSY B39     W 2:30 pm-3:20 pm   
8       D5         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  CAS 218    R 12:30 pm-1:20 pm   
9       D6         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  CGS 421     R 2:00 pm-2:50 pm   
10      D7         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PRB 146     R 3:35 pm-4:25 pm   
11      D8         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS  PRB 150     R 6:30 pm-7:20 pm   
12      DX         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  DIS      NaN             ARR 0: am   
13      L1         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134    M 11:15 am-2:00 pm   
14      L2         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134     T 6:30 pm-9:15 pm   
15      L3         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134    W 8:00 am-10:45 am   
16      L4         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134    W 11:15 am-2:00 pm   
17      L5         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134     W 2:30 pm-5:15 pm   
18      L6         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134     W 6:30 pm-9:15 pm   
19      L7         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134    R 12:30 pm-3:15 pm   
20      L8         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB  SCI 134     R 6:30 pm-9:15 pm   
21      LX         NaN  Enrique Jariwala  LAB      NaN             ARR 0: am
```

You can see that all Open Seats show as NaN values. Is there a function that I can use to access the numbers. I would like to have the number instead of NaN. Here is my code for context.

```
def init_dataframe():

    html_dataframe = pd.read_html(wanted_class_url(course_input))
    dataframe_concatenate = pd.concat(html_dataframe)
    dataframe_semester = html_dataframe[-1]
    dataframe_locate_class = dataframe_semester.loc[:, ]

    return dataframe_locate_class
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: so what exactly you want to do? replace NaN or something else?

Comment: I would like to replace the NaN with the actual number that shows on the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an interesting problem here: the reason for your DataFrames showing `NaN` instead of numbers is that the website, after loading *only the HTML* part is indeed empty. Only after script `view-section.js` has run (in your local browser), the values are filled. So in order to get the same data from your script, you will have to retreive the same data as the website does it. Rough sketch:

Retreive the open seats for each "section". Luckily, the endpoint `openseats.php` accepts an array of course codes like this:

```html
https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/summer/rpc/openseats.php?sections[]=2020SPRGCASMA124%20B7
```

(And apparently, it returns *all* courses' open seats, no matter which code you ask for. So one query should be enough for now.)

The result is the following JSON object:

```
{"time_secs":0.20295810699463,"results":{"2020SPRGCASMA124 A1":"133","2020SPRGCASMA124 A2":"133","2020SPRGCASMA124 A3":"134","2020SPRGCASMA124 B1":"60","2020SPRGCASMA124 B2":"60","2020SPRGCASMA124 B3":"60","2020SPRGCASMA124 B4":"40","2020SPRGCASMA124 B5":"60","2020SPRGCASMA124 B6":"60","2020SPRGCASMA124 B7":"60","2020SPRGCASMA193 A1":"100","2020SPRGCASMA213 A1":"112","2020SPRGCASMA213 B1":"23","2020SPRGCASMA213 B2":"23","2020SPRGCASMA213 B3":"22","2020SPRGCASMA213 B4":"22","2020SPRGCASMA213 B5":"22","2020SPRGCASMA213 C1":"37","2020SPRGCASMA213 C2":"37","2020SPRGCASMA213 C3":"38"}}
```

Transform it into a DataFrame as well, and now you simply have to `.join(..)` both DataFrames. But wait, your original table lacks the cryptic course codes. Those unfortunately only appear within some table cells' `data-section="..."` attribute.

Very unfortunately, the current best available way to get that information is to do the HTML parsing yourself. Entry point: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` (+ many existing questions here on SO).

I hope this gets you started.